# Rename every method skipping the object name

Tags: python

Not sure if this is a valid question or just nonsense, but I have not found an answer online.

I know that it is possible to rename a function in Python this way:

```
SuperMethod = myObject.SuperMethod
```

I would like to know if it is possible to rename every method of an object, that's it, being able to call every method of a particular object without telling explicitly its name (similarly than in VBA by using `with` clause)

I know this will have all kind of naming issues.

Comment: By "rename every method" do you mean *assign all methods to variables*? Generally… well… yeah… but… why?!

Comment: Just to learn if it is possible.. and maybe for its use in a scripting environment when I have a global instance of a class

Comment: You can just do `x = myObject`... then just use `x.whatever`, `x.something_else` as appropriate... that's about as close to the VB with clause you'll get. (that I'm aware of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `globals()` dict with the object's callables after filtering out the internal methods that start and end with `'__'`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def x(self):
        print(self.i + 1)
    def y(self):
        print(self.i + 2)
myObject = A(1)
globals().update({k: getattr(myObject, k) for k, v in A.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('__') and not k.endswith('__') and callable(v)})
x()
y()
```

This outputs:

```
2
3
```

Comment: Actually this is the answer to the question, although I don't recommend using it